# is a pointer an atomic data type in c?

Tags: c, pointers

is a pointer an atomic data type in c? and if not is it a compound type where everything is the same type or mixed? I thought it was atomic but I think I saw a post that said pointers in C++ are compound.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "atomic"?  The usual sense is whether it can be modified in such a way that other threads and/or signal handlers can only see the old or the new value, nothing else, and without causing a data race.  Since C11, no object or type is atomic unless it is declared `_Atomic`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic.  But in that case I do not know what you mean by "compound".

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge I was told an atomic data type is one that cannot be further broken down into other data entities. And that a compound data type is a data type that is comprised of one or more simpler data entities. My confusion was whether I can say a pointer address can be further broken down, maybe by dereferencing or something? I wasn't aware of what you referenced

Comment: Maybe the concept you are looking for is *aggregate type*, i.e. `struct` or array?  No, a pointer isn't a `struct` or an array.  It doesn't have separate individual members or elements. Dereferencing a pointer does not "break it down", it merely uses the pointer as an address and loads or stores the object in memory at that address.

Comment: @sniperking: An 'atomic' type is sometimes used to refer to a non-compound type, but C uses the term 'scalar type' for that. C specifically identifies pointers as a scalar type.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge thanks, your correct, that was just the term I was taught

Comment: However, some target systems interpret their pointer values as if they are aggregates, for example on x86 with the members "segment" and "offset", even if the standard (chapter 6.2.5 paragraph 23) says they are scalar types.